# Is there a way to edit the object returned by a filter GET request?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am working on making a external based License System for a Game Client, but when I filter the GET request by Url using ?key=hwr8y90whwy98 It returns a list of objects rather than the actual object in which I want to edit using a PATCH/PUT.

Is there a good way to return the actual object in which the license check matches? I have only found partial work arounds and most do not provide a good explanation about the workaround.

Currently using this to filter.

```
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
```

Viewset:

```
from .models import License
from .serializers import LicenseSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class LicenseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = License.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LicenseSerializer
    filter_fields = ('key', 'owner')
```

Desired Output:
 I want the filter to give the object to edit so I can then send a PATCH/PUT request to the object.

Comment: try **`?key=hwr8y90whwy98`**

Comment: It is not the `?key=hwr8y90whwy98` part of that is not working, when filtering by a request param it gives back multiple objects where `?key=hwr8y90whwy98` I only need it to give back one object.

Comment: What is `hwr8y90whwy98` value here?

Comment: ``hwr8y90whwy98`` is the key value for a License Model within Django. Example structure https://i.imgur.com/nwDRTPc.png

Comment: Is the `key` field is `unique` in your model?

Comment: yes, which means it will only return one but I can't send a PUT request to that object without changing my url to the id to reference that instance but I need to reference that instance by its `key` field.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I started watching a tutorial series on Django Rest Framework and came across this video due to better wording after talking with JPG.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWZB_F32BDg

Comment: This is hardly an answer. Please provide a summary of the relevant parts of that video that answer your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to achieve the result from start to finish. You can't clip the video as its all relative to it the issue. You had to define a new view and path in urls. Making the query of the view to a single object not multiple.